# Get Random and Unused Index Number Repeatedly For An Array (Maximum call stack error)

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am trying to write a simple "getRandomIndex" function to return a random and **unused** index number for a given array but I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error at `let rndIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - 0)) + 0;`.

```js
const arr = [81, 33, 45, 22, 97, 19, 60];
const usedIndexes = []; // I am trying to store used indexes here

function getRandomIndex() {
  let rndIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - 0)) + 0;
  
  if(usedIndexes.includes(rndIdx)) {
    getRandomIndex();
    return;
  } else {
    usedIndexes.push(rndIdx);
  }

  return rndIdx;
}

// if the array length is more than 10, I always get "call stack size exceed" error.
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // I need to use all elements in the array eventually
  console.log(getRandomIndex());
}
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Any answer? The answers below don't work.

Answer (score 1):

You must check that the length of the array allows for different unused numbers.

```
if (usedIndexes.length>=arr.length) {
  return null
}
```

Comment: I am a little confused, how `usedIndexes.length` might be bigger than `arr.length`? Also I think using `usedIndexes` array is not reasonable, how can I improve my solution without using extra memory if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` the output of `getRandomIndex()` rather than calling it, dumping the output, then returning nothing (which gives you `undefined`)

**Fixed Code**

```js
const arr = [81, 33, 45, 22, 97, 19, 60];
const usedIndexes = []; // I am trying to store used indexes here

function getRandomIndex() {
  let rndIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - 0)) + 0;
  
  if(usedIndexes.includes(rndIdx)) {
    // used to be
    // - getRandomIndex();
    // - return;
    return getRandomIndex();
  } else {
    usedIndexes.push(rndIdx);
  }

  return rndIdx;
}

// if the array length is more than 10, I always get "call stack size exceed" error.
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // I need to use all elements in the array eventually
  console.log(getRandomIndex());
}
```

**Output**

```js
0
2
4
3
1
6
5
```